# Cross database table creation in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have this a bit shattered need to create a table while logged in another database.

I am logged into a database lets say `DB1` and I want to create table into another database call it `DB2`. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

It's only possible if you use [postgres-fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/postgres-fdw.html) to connect to another PostgreSQL database (local in the same instance or remote in another instance).